# Liferay 7.1 Integration with WSO IS 5.6.0 using OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, wso2, liferay, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure SSO login between Liferay 7.1 and WSO2 Identity Server 5.6.0 using OpenID Connect. I've configured the service provider in WSO2 and I've also enabled and configured OpenID Connect in Liferay. At this point I'm able to login in Liferay throught WSO2. I would like to retreive account information (address,phone,username) about user from WSO2 in Liferay.

I tried to add the following scopes *openid email profile address phone* in Liferay config and I've this claims in the service provider but nothing changes: [image]

How can I take those information in Liferay ?

Comment: Is there a way to check the id token in the Liferay side and see if the user attributes are there in it?

Comment: In the UI there isn't a way to check this.

Comment: You can obtain the id_token from Lifray bypassing IS and check whether the required claims are there.